# Limit of average value on interval as it shrinks

Tags: real-analysis, limits, average

Suppose a function $q$ is continuous. Define $q^\ast(b)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b q(x)\;\mathrm{d}x$ to be the average of $q$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

**Question:** How do we prove that $\lim_{b\to a}q^\ast(b)=q(a)$? This is a very straightword intuitive result, but the proof has been eluding me.

I've done the work for when $q$ is monotonically increasing, which is shown below:

$\min_{x\in[a,b]}q(x)=q(a)$ and $\max_{x\in[a,b]}q(x)=q(b)$ {Property of monotonically increasing function}

If this is true, then we should be able to say that

$q(a)\leq\underbrace{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b q(x)\;\mathrm{d}x}_{q^\ast}\leq q(b)$

The squeeze theorem can be used since
$$\lim_{b\to a}q(b)=\lim_{b\to a}q(a)=q(a)$$

Thus, by the squeeze theorem, $$\lim_{b\to a}q^\ast(b)=q(a)$$

The argument for a decreasing function is essentially the same (with $q(a)$ in the place of $q(b)$).

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\min_{x \in [a, b]} q(x) \leq q^*(b) \leq \max_{x \in [a, b]} q(x).$$

Comment: How do we prove that the min approaches max or vice versa? Or is that unneccessary?

Comment: @Kcronix think about the hypotesis you have on $q$.

Comment: Both go to $q(a)$ because $q$ is continuous by assumption.

Comment: Are you saying that in the limit we obtain $x\in [a,a]$?